# Referring to Gentile Priest as "Father"

Tags: halacha, names, christianity

Is it permissible to either refer to or address a gentile priest as "Father XXXXXXXXX"?
What alternatives might there be?

Comment: Should be no different than calling the Pope, Pope.

Comment: Is there any reason you ask specifically about a gentile priest? Do you think the rule might be different for a _Yisrael m'shumad_ priest?

Comment: Very similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/32110

Comment: Christianity perceives baptism as spiritual rebirth, and Christian priests are usually the ones baptizing and preaching (just as parents giving birth to children, and then teaching or educating them).

Answer (score 1):

Rav Berel Wein [seems](https://www.angelfire.com/super2/eshworld/stamtorah/archive-5761/kedoshim.html) to feel it would be permitted to call a priest by the honorary title of "father":

> One Motzei Shabbos (Saturday night), my Rosh Yeshiva, Rabbi Berel Wein
> shlita, was visiting a member of his congregation in the hospital. The
> patient was on the top floor and after the visit Rabbi Wein prepared
> to take the elevator down. The hospital has two sets of elevators, on
> opposite sides of the hall. As Rabbi Wein approached one elevator, he
> saw that standing at the opposite elevator was a Roman Catholic priest
> in full regalia. He too had just finished visiting one of his own
> parishioners and was leaving. The priest had just pushed the button
> for his elevator and Rabbi Wein proceeded to push the button for his
> elevator. Seeing Rabbi Wein still dressed in his Shabbos regalia, the
> priest looked over at him and said, "Good evening, Rabbi". Rabbi Wein
> turned and politely replied, "Good evening, **Father**." And then they
> both stood quietly waiting for the elevator to come.    There were a
> number of people standing between the two clergymen. As they watched
> the proceedings they stood transfixed, as if paralyzed. They felt that
> the theological dispute of the centuries was about to be settled right
> before their eyes- which spiritual leader could command the first
> elevator.    As Rabbi Wein would say, "Contrary to popular belief, G-d
> is on the side of Rabbis" and his elevator came first. The door slid
> open, Rabbi Wein smiled and magnanimously waved everyone in, including
> the priest. As the elevator began its descent, the priest looked at
> Rabbi Wein with a sly twinkle in his eye and remarked, "Rabbi, what
> would you have said if my elevator had come first?" Rabbi Wein
> replied, "**Father**, you can't prove anything from a descending
> elevator."