# Calling a Muslim leader an "Imam"

Tags: halacha, names, islam

Is there a halachic issue with referring to a Muslim imam by the title "Imam" (or "Imam **__**" with the person's name inserted in place of the underscore)?

Here are the thoughts that lead me to ask this question: The Arabic word "imam" means something like "leader" ([according to Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%A5%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%85#Arabic)), which seems like a pretty harmless term to use. On the other hand, perhaps lending this sort of *kavod* to a Muslim religious leader is inappropriate in that it legitimizes Islam, which we may not want to promote. (A possible precedent for this could be how Rav Moshe Feinstein writes ראביי instead of רב when he is referring to non-Orthodox Jewish clergy; even though both terms have the same etymological origin, Rav Moshe does not want to legitimize non-Orthodox Judaism through the use of the honorific רב.)

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31928

Comment: what does imam mean? then you will have an answer

Comment: According to Wiktionary (http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%A5%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%85#Arabic), it literally means something like "leader".

Comment: Why would "leader" be a term that would be Asur to use?

Comment: @SethJ I was wondering whether it's appropriate to give kavod in this manner to someone who is publicizing ideas that go somewhat counter to Torah. Note that this is a fairly well-known issue in the context of using the term "Rabbi" to refer to non-Orthodox Jewish clergy (e.g. Rav Moshe writes ראביי instead of רבי).

Comment: That doesn't clarify my confusion. Why is "leader" a problem? You're not saying "my leader", are you? It's not like "father", either, which suggests something more than a simple acknowledgment that other people follow him.

Comment: Perhaps related to these comments: the comments on http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3787

Comment: @Malper What does "ראביי" mean besides "Rabbi"?

Comment: That's exactly my point. R' Moshe did use the word "ראביי" which means "Rabbi" (lit. "my leader", though in corrupted form), but he wouldn't give kavod to non-Orthodox Jewish clergy by calling them Rebeim). Similarly, could there be a problem with giving kavod to Muslim clergy by directly calling them by this honorific title?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Are you sure? We don't have halachic *smicha* nowadays.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin (1) It's not obvious that one may only call a person "Rav" if they were notel reshus. (2) The term "Rabbi" was certainly not just an honor in the time of the gemara.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin There's a big controversy about the correct nikkud... it might have been Rabbi, Rebbi, Ribbi, or even Rubbi (no joke).